# Disable IPv6 when connected to (specific) VPN network

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, ipv6

In most of the places I work, IPv6 is supported. For my research work I also have VPN access to the university. However, this university does not support IPv6, so IPv4 data is routed over the VPN when connected, but IPv6 is routed over my local router.

There are various websites (e.g. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/) which provide certain content for universities, based on their IPs, without login or free of charge. Since these websites support IPv4 and IPv6, and Ubuntu/my browser prefers IPv6, I can't access the provided content even if I'm connected to the university VPN. This only works if I deactivate IPv6 (manually, e.g. by dropping the IPv6 ip address).

Is there any way to deactivate my computer's IPv6 using Network Manager when connecting to this specific VPN? Selecting "Disable" in the Network Manager's IPv6 settings, it disables IPv6 only for the University connection (which has no IPv6 either). How to globally disable/block IPv6 traffic while connected to this University VPN?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 with Network Manager.

Comment: The VPN provider should be taking care of this by either providing IPv6 (it's 2019 after all! there's no reasonable excuse anymore) or preventing its use while the VPN is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Check your VPN interface with `ifconfig`. Denote your interface name.

Create a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`, containing

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "tun0" ]; then
  sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
  sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
fi
```

In case you use tap or another VPN interface replace the line

`if [ "$IFACE" = "tun0" ]; then`

with

`if [ "$IFACE" = "tap0" ]; then`

or

`if [ "$IFACE" = "your_denoted_vpn_interface_name" ]; then`

Comment: to add it  make the script executable - chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/script_name

Comment: script name is sensitive—if you use `whatever.sh` it doesn't work, periods are forbidden. unfortunately this method doesn't restart my ipv6 once I turn off the VPN (not even with a parallel script setting the `disable_ipv6` options to 0 on ifdown). for now I have to restart wifi to get an ipv6 back.